# BIRT formatting - merge cells on specific rows

Tags: birt

How do I merge cells for specific rows in BIRT? Something similar to using colspan when creating a table in HTML. The data is extracted from a database and returns a fixed number of rows.

Specifically I want to convert a BIRT report that looks like this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it is possible to do this within an onCreate event for the cells.

But depending on your use case, it may be sufficient to duplicate the detail row.
Keep the cells as is in the first detail row and merge them in the second row.

Determine a condition when to merge cells and when not.

Use this as an visibility expression for the first and second detail row like this:

First row: `should_merge(...)`

Second row: `!should_merge(...)`

Comment: Thanks for your input. I will try your suggestions.